# Ionic/AngularJS Infinite scroll without call load more

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, infinite-scroll

I'd like to implement an infinite scroll, but without call a load more function everytime.

Let's think I've download an array of 1000 items from Parse. I'd like to show 10 items and then add more and more items to my list using ng-repeat from a local array.

I think the best solution is to implement a directive, but maybe there is something already done...

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you could do it as a directive, but regardless, you are going to need some sort of `loadMore` function. To put in other words, you are going to need to detect when the user has scrolled to a particular position, and perform some updating function.

While your own directive might be better at encapsulating your specific requirement, you could achieve what you want with any other current infinite scrolling plugin. Simply keep two versions of your array in your model. One is the data, while the other is the data that the user sees. If your arrays are of objects, then both should be able to work on the same items.

For example:

```
var data = [...];
var position = 0;
var pageSize = 10;
$scope.viewable = [];

$scope.loadMore = function(){
    $scope.viewable = $scope.viewable.concat(data.slice(position, position + pageSize));
    position += pageSize;
};
```

---

Update:

If this is something you need to implement often, but don't want to implement your own scrolling related directive, you could encapsulate the idea above in a factory that manages multiversion arrays. You would still have to hook the `loadMore`, and setup the multiversion, but your controller and view code would look like the following:

```
// the data you loaded somewhere
var data = [...];
$scope.specialArray = PageableArrayFactory.create(data);

// then in your html
ng-repeat="item in specialArray.viewItems"
// where you put your infinite scroll
infinite-scroll="specialArray.loadMore()"
```

`PageableArrayFactory` just needs to be a factory that takes in your big data array, and keeps track of a viewable copy array like my initial example. It shouldn't be too hard to implement, and can then be reused with a single line of code in any controller after you load your data.

---

Another example:

You could also build a custom filter on `$index` (or use `ng-show/if`), so that `ng-repeat` only shows the items that you want. You will still need to hook `loadMore()` though if you want to use existing infinite scroller code, which means you will still need something my factory example.

Comment: I understand your solution, but I have 5/6 controllers and I feel really hard to implement this all the time for each controller/list in my app...:-(

Comment: Well in that case, you could wrap my idea in your own directive, but then you will need to implement the scroll related code. Alternatively I have updated my answer to provide a reusable method where you can still use existing infinite scroll plugins.

Comment: Much better, but still not :-(

Comment: I feel  we can find something better

Comment: Better is subjective. All my suggestions are valid examples that work. How about you improve your question so that it is more black and white, so that you don't waste the time of people trying to help you.

Comment: Sorry Matt, it's not my intention. I just feel we can find something more reusable. And thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277697/matt-way)'s solution is perfectly fine. Especially considering you've mentioned you want to use `ng-repeat` and you want to paginate your result.

It doesn't seem to be a huge effort to implement what he's suggesting. The other option is to use `collection-repeat`, especially for [performances](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/collectionRepeat/).

The implementation is very simple:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item collection-repeat="item in items">
    {{item}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

and you don't have to be worried about loading all the items together as the framework will be responsible to load chunks of information for you. 
The only drawback - as far as I am aware - is you cannot control the number of items you want to display.